# Get all the Fields including non-direct fields which are from inheritance in Element using AbstractProcessor

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I'm writing a tool to generate JSON schema out of POJOs and enhance it with more data using some custom-defined annotations.
I use AbstractProcessor & Gradle to run the AnnotationProcessor during the compile time. The biggest problem I have is to get the list of fields within the class (Element in this case):

```
public class JsonSchemaProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(JsonSchema.class).stream().forEach(classElement ->
            classElement.getEnclosedElements().stream()
                .filter(e -> ElementKind.FIELD == e.getKind())
                .forEach(/* DO SOMETHING WITH IT */)
        );
    }
}
```

**getEnclosedElements** just return the directly defined fields. For example, if the class inherited from another class I can not have the field defined the parent in my list. Any suggestion to find out all the fields including those that come from inheritance?

Comment: You'll have to walk up the class hierarchy. See [`TypeElement#getSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/TypeElement.html#getSuperclass()).

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. I'll post my implementation if no one comes up with a better solution.